# Clearing the buffer-Winsock

Tags: c++, sockets, client, buffer, winsock

Here is my code for the client program I have made in C++ using winsock in Windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include<sstream>
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#pragma comment(lib,"WS2_32.lib");

struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
         *ptr = NULL,
         hints;

int main()
{
WSAData wsadata;
int iResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
char *sendbuf = "1,2,3,4!!";
char recvbuf[512];



iResult=WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsadata);
if(iResult!=0)
{
    std::cout<<"WSAStartup failed"<<iResult<<std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

char arr[20]="localhost";

iResult = getaddrinfo(arr, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0)
{
    std::cout<<"getaddrinfo failed: "<<iResult;
    getchar();
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
ptr=result;
ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
ptr->ai_protocol);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    std::cout<<"Error at socket(): "<<WSAGetLastError();
    getchar();
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
{
    std::cout<<"Unable to connect to server!"<<std::endl;
    getchar();
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}



for(;;)
{
int i=15;
int x=12;
int z=1;
iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);
std::cout<<"Recieved data: "<<recvbuf<<std::endl;
}

iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);

if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    std::cout<<"shutdown failed: "<<WSAGetLastError();
    getchar();
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

if (iResult == 0)
    std::cout<<"Connection closed\n";
else
    std::cout<<"recv of client failed: "<<WSAGetLastError();

iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    std::cout<<"shutdown failed: "<<WSAGetLastError();
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

The information that I am receiving is fine. The only problem is that I want to clear the buffer every time I receive some data.
The output of the current code if I send a,b,c,d is something like

a,b,c,d

aa,bb,cc,dd

aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd

While I want my output to be a,b,c,d as it keeps receiving this information again and again. How to do this?

Comment: are you sure the problem is not on the sending side? If it were a problem clearing the buffer on the receiving side, you'd get "a,b,c,da,b,c,da,b,c,d....", wouldn't you?

Comment: @Andrew I am sending four different strings containing a,b,c and finally d. On the sending side I am concatenating them. so its like

string a="a";

string b="b";

string c="c";

string d="d";

a=a+","+b+","+c+",",+d;

sendbuf=a.c_str(); (Converting the string into a char*)

And then I am sending it.

Comment: @Andrew I cannot change the data on the sending side as the send function takes a cons char pointer as its input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code in what you provided looks like an infinite loop:

```
for(;;)
{
int i=15;
int x=12;
int z=1;
iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);
std::cout<<"Recieved data: "<<recvbuf<<std::endl;
}
```

On top of that, it outputs `recvbuf` as if it were a string, but there is no guarantee that it will be `\0` terminated, and will likely lead to undefined behavior if you actually read the full `DEFAULT_BUFLEN` bytes of data. I would suggest a `string` conversion before printing. But before that, the return value of `recv` should be checked.

```
iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);
if (iResult <= 0) break;
std::cout<<"Received data: " <<std::string(recvbuf,iResult)<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Yes, I have used an infinite loop because the data is coming continuously and I need to output the data continuously. Why have you supplied iResult as an argument to *std::string* though?

Comment: @PrakharMohan: There is still the issue of not checking the result of `recv`, and making sure you are not reading past the end of your `recvbuf` (or just past the actual number of bytes that you read).

Comment: I did implement your code and the output remains the same. No change.

Comment: @PrakharMohan: You should do a [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) trace then to see what bytes are on the wire. Wireshark is a packet capture tool.